# getJSON not ready with returning data before showing the data

Tags: jquery

something strange here: I use a $.getJSON to get data from the database. It returns valid data, but it doesn't show in the inputbox afterwards. When I insert an alert("bla") after the json call, it does show the data. My assumption is that the json call isn't ready yet when showing the data on the page. Is there a way to wait for the json call to finish? This is my code:

```
    $.getJSON("mvc/models/predictions.php?action=getpredictions&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {

            // Replace markup on page
            prediction[1] = data[0].prediction1; 
        });

        // Create output
        <input type='text' name='prediction1' size='5' value='" + prediction[1] + "' />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you need to populate the input box after the ajax call has returned. You can alter the input value inside the JSON return function, like so:

```
$.getJSON("mvc/models/predictions.php?action=getpredictions&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
  $('input[name="prediction1"]').val(data[0].prediction1);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that this json request is nested within another json request. When I move the input box (and other code) into this json, the json data from the other json is not available anymore to use in this code (it returns an error).

Comment: Would you please be able to post your full code so we can debug it? It should work fine, just ensure that the json requests don't reference the same variable (ie, in the first json request, call function(data1), second json request function(data2) etc)

Comment: I've created a little fiddle to show 2 nested json requests, with the result of the first json request being accessed in the nested request. Hopefully this help you. http://jsfiddle.net/thfjh/

Comment: See http://imageshack.us/f/171/jqueryu.png/ I get two errors on this line: "if (data2[0].prediction1 != ""){". Error 1: "data1[x] is undefined" and error 2: "data2 is null".

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the data. Are you using FireBug to track the requests? I'd start with testing the first JSON call, looping through the user_ids to see if they come out correctly, like so: $.getJSON("mvc/models/predictions.php?action=getgamerounds&jsoncallback=?", function(data1) {
 for (var x = 0; x < data1.length; x++) {
  console.log(data1[x].user_id);
 }
});

Comment: Strange. If I do this:   console.log('Test '+x);
  console.log('Gameround: '+data1[0].gameround_id);
  console.log('Gameround: '+data1[x].gameround_id); Then the first"x" shows a number, the second log shows the gameround_id but the third log doesn't show anything. That x is from data1[x] of the first getJSON and is now outputted in the secong getJSON.

Comment: Found it! I use data1[x] in my second getJSON and for a certain reason (have to find out why) the value of x is 1 instead of 0. And I have only 1 row of data, so with x=1 it doens't show any data....